# I am trying to implement transfer learning using mobileNet from the website of tensorflow on catvsdog dataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

It takes too much time to train the classifier,so can we implement  Repeat function so that  no. of times dataset  can be repeated?

```
def repeat(train_batches, count=5):

    # return train_batches,count
    for image_batch, label_batch in train_batches.take(1):
        #pass
        break
       # image_batch.shape
       # repeat(train_batches,2)
       #def repeat(train_batches, count):

       # return train_batches,count
    image_batch.shape
```

Comment: No clue what your question is. You're using a for loop and using break just after? could you pleas elaborate your question.

Comment: in "for" loop if we write pass ,it will take too much time to pass it, hence i have written break so it will take only 1 batch of dataset to train, also we can use repeat function also, to repeat no. of times to train dataset, now my question is how can we implement repeat function? mentioned here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat